# how to extract values of tensor type from multiple dictionnary in a pandasseries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytorch, torch

I use Bert model to tokenize a dataframe, the output is variable of class pandasSeries which contains a set of dictionnary representing the vectors of each row of the original dataframe(column). What I want to do is to extract in one column dataframe all the values which correspond to the key 'input_ids' in each dictionnary.

```
path_to_lge = "flaubert/flaubert_small_cased"
flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_lge, do_lowercase=False)

#texte is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

encoding = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode_plus(x, add_special_tokens=True, return_token_type_ids=False, truncation=True, padding=True, return_attention_mask=True)))

print(type(encoding)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(encoding)

0     [input_ids, attention_mask]
1     [input_ids, attention_mask]
2     [input_ids, attention_mask]
3     [input_ids, attention_mask]
...
```

When I want to get the different element , I used an index but somehow I cannot retrieve all values of key'input_ids' by passing just the name of keys as it throw an error and saying the element does not exist
when acccessing element one  by one I use index and then follow by the key as below

```
print(encoding[0])
{'input_ids': [0, 93, 106, 97, 26, 578, 14, 535, 61, 6823, 21, 7652, 19, 151, 11804, 1934, 75, 20340, 75, 10777 , 1006, 2986, 15, 200, 75, 50, 1779, 8475, 58, 15, 200, 24023,  1], 'attention_ mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

print(encoding[2])
{'input_ids': [0, 1934, 75, 20340, 75, 10777 , 1006, 2986, 15, 200, 75, 50, 1779, 8475, 58, 15, 200, 24023,  1], 'attention_ mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

I want to extract all values from 'input_ids" and "attention_mask" in order to pass it to the FlauBertmodel in order to get the vectors.

I try to append all value of of input_ids in each dictionnary and passing to a dataframe but it is not working, my tentative return an empty dataframe.

```
encoding_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['input_ids', 'attention_mask'])
for e in encoding:
   encoding_df.append(e['input_ids'], e['attention_mask'])
print(encoding_df)

what I get : Empty DataFrame Columns: [input_ids, attention_mask] Index: []
```

Perhaps someone can help me ?

What I expect :

```
input_ids                      attention_mask
[0, 16, 175, 20, 4146, ...]    [1,1,1,1,1,...]
[51, 27, 42, 1391, 14,...]     [1,1,1,1,1...]
[157, 48, 2158, 19, 245,...]   [1,1,1,1,1,..]
```